# How to connect via reverse SSH tunnel to other IP of host in same subnet?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

Situation:
Macbook which has IP 192.168.1.6 (at home).
Linux VM which has IP 10.0.2.15 as it runs as a VM guest in 'shared network' mode. From the guest, the Mac always has a fixed IP 10.0.2.2 regardless of the used network.
To access SSH to the VM I use `ssh -fN -D 2023:localhost:22 user@10.0.2.2` from the Linux VM, so I can reach the VM by ssh'ing into localhost at port 2023 by using the command
`ssh -p 2023 vmuser@localhost`. But when I want to ssh into the VM from another machine in my local 192.168.1.x network (e.g. Raspberry Pi or a cellphone) I try accessing it by `ssh -p 2023 vmuser@192.168.1.6`, but it says 'connection refused'.
It is not a firewall in the VM as otherwise I could not connect from the Mac neither. And the firewall on the Mac allows SSH connections into it (and presumably via nonstandard ports like 2023), of which the latter is forwarded to the VM Linux.
The same occurs when I port forward 80 and 443 of the Linux VM via a reverse tunnel.
It appears that the -D FORWARDED:HOSTIP:ORIGINAL only works when I connect to the exact HOSTIP, which is localhost in this case and the indoor IP address like 192.168.1.6 is refused.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually when you are using command "ssh -fN -D 2023:localhost:22 user@10.0.2.2" you already see that the endpoint is "localhost(the ssh server itself)"...

When you successfully ssh to the SSH server , you can actually check the port "2023" with command netstat -n -l -p | grep 2023, you should see it like:

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2023

That's why other server in the same subnet won't be able to conenct to it, as it binds locallly as 127.0.0.1 .
But as "SSH reverse tunnel" is always a tunneling back to localhost, I don't think there is a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, assuming your tunnel command is `ssh -fN -R 2023:...` instead of `ssh -fN -D 2023:...`.

Now, to allow remote hosts to connect, you need to specify bind_address in `ssh -R`, the easiest would be to use `*` for that which means all addresses. Additionally, for security reasons, listening to interfaces other than loopback is prevented in sshd by default, so you need to set the option `GatewayPorts` to `yes` in `sshd_config` (in linux this is in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, I assume it is the same in the Mac.

So to summarize:

- Add `GatewayPorts yes` to your (macbook) `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
- Restart the ssh server.
- Replace your tunnel command by this one: `ssh -fN -R *:2023:localhost:22 user@10.0.2.2`

(I didn't try it, but `*` should work according to the manual page. If not, try `0.0.0.0` or `192.168.1.6` instead, although the last one would prevent you to connect locally using `localhost`).

Answer (score 0):

I indeed meant -R, not -D in my original question.
Indeed that works, setting `GatewayPorts yes` on the Mac in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` did the trick. Indeed, the folder is the same as on Linux.